# QGIS expression function month() does not return month in MM format

Tags: qgis, expression, date, format

Using QGIS expressions, the following expression returns `5`:

```
month('2012-05-12') -> 5
```

[The help](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#month), however, says that the output of *this very expression* is `05`. I don't see an option to format the output to a double digit number. I tried creating the output as string or integer, without success.

A workaround would be the following expression. However, this is not very elegant and still, based on the help, there should be an option to get a double digit output from the function `month()`.

```
right(0 || month('2012-05-12'), 2) -> 05
```

Comment: I am of the opinion that these problems should be reported in the QGIS repository via issue or in the QGIS-developer list:

an alternative: lpad(month('2012-05-12'),2,'0')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other solution:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#lpad

```
lpad(month('2012-05-12'),2,'0') → '05'
```

[image]

but I remain of the idea that the help error should be reported via issue in the QGIS repository

[image]